# Stuck on showing $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(n^2+3n-7)}{n^3+1}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show if this series converges or diverges and I know it converges since for very large values of n, 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(n^2+3n-7)}{n^3+1}$$ becomes $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n1}{n}$$
which is convergent from the alternating series test since lim 1/n = 0 and 1/n is a decreasing sequence. I am going back and forth using the limit comparison test and alternating series test and can't seem to come up with anything. So right now i have $$\frac{(-1)^n(n^2+3n-7)}{n^3+1} \lt \frac{(-1)^n(n^2+3n-7)}{n^3}$$
and whenever I try to show the right handed side to be convergent I come back to the same problem as with the left hand side.

Comment: Divide the partial sum of the series in partial fractions, then take all the limits. All parts of the series will converge. Just compare each part with $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

Comment: If you have trouble comparing things as $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n+k}$ where $k$ is a constant, just change the index, then it will be a subseries of $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ or $\sum\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$.

Comment: Comparison tests don't work very well when the sequence is alternating.

Comment: If the terms shrink fastly enough the (-1)^n is immaterial to convergence.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. As $n \to \infty$, we have
$$
(-1)^n\frac{n^2+3n-7}{n^3+1}=\frac{(-1)^n}n\cdot\frac{1+\frac3n-\frac7{n^2}}{1+\frac1{n^3}}=\frac{(-1)^n}n+O\left(\frac1{n^2} \right)
$$ the initial series, being the sum of a *conditionally* convergent series and an *absolute* convergent series is then *conditionally* convergent.

Answer (score 1):

We can write
$$\frac{n^2+3n-7}{n^3+1}= \frac{n^2-n +1}{n^3+1} + \frac{4(n +1)}{n^3+1} - \frac{12}{n^3+1}= \\
= \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{4}{n^2-n +1} - \frac{12}{n^3+1}.
$$
Now, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{ \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}}$ converges conditionally, however, $4\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{ \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2-n +1}}$ and $12\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{ \frac{(-1)^n}{n^3+1}}$ are absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 1):

The alternating or Dirichlet test tells us that if

$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^Na_n\right|<L$$

is bounded and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$$

where $b_n$ is monotone for all $n>M$, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nb_n$ converges.  In this case, we have $a_n=(-1)^n$ and $b_n=\frac{n^2+3n-7}{n^3+1}$, where $b_n$ is monotone for all $n\ge3$.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for the correction.  :)

Comment: How can you tell it is monotone for n >= 3

Comment: @reifi You take derivative and find the zeros.

Comment: @ Simple Art The derivative of b_n is a bit messy isn't it? You just found the zeroes for it?

Comment: @reifi You only need to find an integer value near the root.  No need for exactness.

Answer (score 1):

If you show

$$\left (\frac{x^2+3x-7}{x^3+1} \right)' <0$$

for large $x,$ then for large $n$ the terms of your series are decreasing in absolute value, and you can apply the alternating series test.

Comment: wow that is a surprisingly powerful test. Is the proof simple? (I probably should resolve to prove it myself)

Answer (score 0):

I'll take the opportunity for showing some useful techniques for the manipulation of similar series.

---

Let $\omega=\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\overline{\omega}=\omega^{-1}=\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. By the residue theorem
$$ \frac{x^2+3x-7}{x^3+1} = \frac{-3}{x+1}+\frac{2+\frac{2i}{\sqrt{3}}}{x-\omega}+\frac{2-\frac{2i}{\sqrt{3}}}{x-\overline{\omega}} \tag{1}$$
where:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{-3(-1)^n}{n+1} = -3\log(2)\tag{2} $$
so the original series equals
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n(n^2+3n-7)}{n^3+1} &=& -3\log(2)-4-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n 4n}{n^2+n+1}\\&\stackrel{ILP}{=}&-3\log(2)-4-2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{3}\cos\left(\frac{s\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{s\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{3}\cosh\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}\,ds\\&=&-3\log(2)-4-\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{3}\cos\left(s\sqrt{3}\right)-\sin\left(s\sqrt{3}\right)}{\cosh\left(s\right)}\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$
where *ILP* stands for [Inverse Laplace Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform). By the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), the absolute value of the last integral appearing in the RHS of $(3)$ is not larger than
$$ \frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{\cosh s} = \frac{4 \pi}{\sqrt{3}}.\tag{4}$$
We may also simplify the RHS of $(3)$ a little more and state that:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n(n^2+3n-7)}{n^3+1} = -\log(8)-4-\frac{2\pi}{\cosh\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}+\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(s\sqrt{3})}{\cosh(s)}\,ds.\tag{5}$$